# How to avoid temporary file creation during FTP using spring integration

Tags: ftp, sftp, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration version 2.0.3  to  send files to remote system via FTP with spring-integration-ftp `outbound-channel-adapter`.  By default, during FTP the file will be created with an extenstion ".writing"  and once the copying finished, it will be renamed by removing the ".writing" suffix.

But there is no permission to rename the file, once it is copied to remote location.  in the latest [Spring integration reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound) I fond that the peroperty `use-temporary-file-name` can be set to `false` to avoid using temporary file naming during FTP.

Is there any way to achieve the functionality with Spring integration ver 2.0.x ?

Answer (score 1):

No; this was added in 2.1.x; I would recommend upgrading to 2.2.6.

Be aware that if you transfer a file without a suffix, there is a danger that the receiving application might see the file before it is completely written (that is why the default is the way it is).

Comment: Thanks Gray for the reply.  Let me check if I can upgrade the version.